# GCM Networkmanager - Tasks not running when app gets killed

Tags: android, task, gcm-network-manager

I'm using `GCMNetworkManager` to load some data or set some data into a database.
But for some reason, the tasks do not run if my application gets killed (in taskmanager or because of memory reasons).

Is there a posibility to run the tasks even if the application is dead?

Here is my code to enable the tasks:

```
public void enableTasks(Context context) {
    GcmNetworkManager networkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(context);
    scheduleTask(networkManager, BackgroundTasks.WORK_THROUGH_QUEUE);
    scheduleTask(networkManager, BackgroundTasks.LOAD_MONTAGEORDERS);
    scheduleTask(networkManager, BackgroundTasks.UPDATE_MONIINFO);

    PreferenceDao.getInstance().setTasksSet(true);
}

 private void scheduleTask(GcmNetworkManager networkManager, String taskTag) {
    Task task = BackgroundTasks.getTask(taskTag);

    if (task != null) {
        networkManager.schedule(task);
    }
}
```

The class `BackgroundTasks`

```
 @Override
public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Task runs: " + taskParams.getTag());

    try {
        switch (taskParams.getTag()) {
            case WORK_THROUGH_QUEUE:
                workThroughQueues();
                return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
            case LOAD_MONTAGEORDERS:
                MainController.getInstance().getMontageOrderController().refreshMontageOrders();
                return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
            case UPDATE_MONIINFO:
                UpdateHelper.getInstance().updateInfos();
                return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
            default:
                return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_FAILURE;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_FAILURE;
    }

}

 public static Task getTask(String taskTag) {
    switch (taskTag) {
        case WORK_THROUGH_QUEUE:
            return buildTask(taskTag, 300L, 60L);
        case LOAD_MONTAGEORDERS:
            return buildTask(taskTag, 900L, 60L);
        case UPDATE_MONIINFO:
            return buildTask(taskTag, 1800L, 120L);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

private static Task buildTask(String tag, long period, long flex) {
    return new PeriodicTask.Builder()
            .setTag(tag)
            .setPeriod(period)
            .setFlex(flex)
            .setService(BackgroundTasks.class)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .build();
}
```

Service in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service
        android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.BackgroundTasks"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Are you using a Service?

Comment: yes, i updated my question with the service

Comment: Go into your android terminal and type in: `adb shell dumpsys activity service GcmService` and tell us what it says. It should tell you 1. If your task has ran and 2.  why it didn't run if it did get scheduled

Comment: i'm using jobscheduler now. works a little bit better but still not perfect